# Why is last line duplicated when appending to a text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas

My code is duplicating the last line when i append it into a text file.

An example input file is

```
[headline - https://www.rfa.org/cantonese/news/us-pompeo-06012020072305.html]
This
some-text-here

[date - https://www.rfa.org/cantonese/news/us-pompeo-06012020072305.html]
https://www.rfa.org/cantonese/news/us-pompeo-06012020072305.html/US-Pompeo.mp3

[headline - https://www.rfa.org/cantonese/news/htm/tw-uk-06012020113435.html]
Is
some-text-here

[date - https://www.rfa.org/cantonese/news/htm/tw-uk-06012020113435.html]
https://www.rfa.org/cantonese/news/htm/tw-uk-06012020113435.html/tw-su.mp3

[headline - https://www.rfa.org/cantonese/news/wang-06012020103828.html]
Test
some-text-here

[date - https://www.rfa.org/cantonese/news/wang-06012020103828.html]
https://www.rfa.org/cantonese/news/wang-06012020103828.html/wang.mp3

[headline - https://www.rfa.org/cantonese/news/us-wang-06012020135251.html]
TEST
some-text-here

[headline - https://www.rfa.org/cantonese/news/htm/hk-chan-06012020073718.html]
TEST
some-text-here

[headline - https://www.rfa.org/cantonese/news/ear/ear-state-06012020035108.html]
TEST
some-text-here

[date - https://www.rfa.org/cantonese/news/ear/ear-state-06012020035108.html]
https://www.rfa.org/cantonese/news/ear/ear-state-06012020035108.html/EarState.mp3

[headline - https://www.rfa.org/cantonese/news/htm/hk-innocent-06012020114634.html]
TEST
some-text-here
```

However, the output files always append the last line twice for some reason. And I get this for `ear-state-06012020035108.txt`.

```
TEST
some-text-here
some-text-here
```

You can see that some-text-here is being duplicated. I simply want to get all the text into a text file. However, for some reason it's appending only the last line at the bottom twice.

Here is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import re
import requests

def tabulate_headlines(text="", filename="", verbose=0):
    """Tabulates the information from either a text string (text) or from the
    text read from a file (filename) and returns a dataframe.

    Example:
        # Case: from text
        df = tabulate_headlines(text=s, filename="", verbose=1)
        # Case: from a file
        df = tabulate_headlines(text="", filename="input.txt", verbose=1)
    """

    ## Read text from input file
    if not text and (filename is not None):
        with open(filename, "r") as f:
            text = f.read()
    if text is not None:
        ## Define regex patterns for
        #  - headline-text and corresponding source-id
        #  - headline_url
        #  - date_url
        #  - mp3_url
        #  - source_id from (headline, date and mp3)
        headline_text_pat = r"\n?\[headline - https://.*/(.*?)\.html\]\n((.*\n)+?)\n"
        headline_pat = r".*\[headline - (https://.*?\.html?)[,\]]"
        date_pat = r".*\[date - (https://.*?\.html?)[,\]]"
        mp3_pat = r".*\n(https://.*?\.html/.*?\.mp3)\s*\n"
        source_id_pat = r"https://.*/(.*?)\.html" # headline, date
        source_id_pat_mp3 = r"https://.*/(.*?).html/.*?\.mp3" # mp3

        ## Compile regex-patterns for speed
        headline_text_pat = re.compile(headline_text_pat)
        headline_pat = re.compile(headline_pat)
        date_pat = re.compile(date_pat)
        mp3_pat = re.compile(mp3_pat)
        source_id_pat = re.compile(source_id_pat)
        source_id_pat_mp3 = re.compile(source_id_pat_mp3)

        ## Extract headlines (texts)
        #  and store in a pandas.Series object: headlines
        headline_data = headline_text_pat.findall(text + '\n[')
        headline_texts = []
        source_ids = []
        for headline in headline_data:
            source_id, headline_text = headline[0], ''.join(headline[1:]).strip()
            headline_texts.append(headline_text)
            source_ids.append(source_id)
        # Save as a pandas.Series object: headlines
        headlines = pd.Series(data=headline_texts, index=source_ids)

        ## Extract the urls (for headline, date, mp3)
        headline_urls = headline_pat.findall(text)
        date_urls = date_pat.findall(text)
        mp3_urls = mp3_pat.findall(text)

        ## Make temporary dataframes
        df_headline = pd.DataFrame({'headline_url': headline_urls})
        df_date = pd.DataFrame({'date_url': date_urls})
        df_mp3 = pd.DataFrame({'mp3_url': mp3_urls})

        ## Process temporary dataframes to
        df_headline['source_id'] = (df_headline['headline_url']
                                    .str.replace(source_id_pat, r"\1", regex=True))
        df_date['source_id'] = (df_date['date_url']
                                .str.replace(source_id_pat, r"\1", regex=True))
        df_mp3['source_id'] = (df_mp3['mp3_url']
                            .str.replace(source_id_pat_mp3, r"\1", regex=True))
        df_headline.set_index('source_id', inplace=True)
        df_date.set_index('source_id', inplace=True)
        df_mp3.set_index('source_id', inplace=True)

        ## Combine headlines, dates and mp3s together
        df = pd.concat([df_headline, df_date, df_mp3], axis=1)
        df['source_id'] = df.index
        df['headline_text'] = headlines
        df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    else:
        df = None
    if verbose>0:
        print(df)
    return df


def download_mp3(url, filename='out.mp3', output_dir=''):
    if not filename.endswith('.mp3'):
        filename += '.mp3'
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
    # update filename (add path if applicable)
    filename = update_filename(filename=filename,
                               output_dir=output_dir)
    # write to mp3 file
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(r.content)

def write_headline(text, filename='out.txt', output_dir=''):
    if not filename.endswith('.txt'):
        filename += '.txt'
    # update filename (add path if applicable)
    filename = update_filename(filename=filename,
                               output_dir=output_dir)
    # write to txt file
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write(text)

def update_filename(filename, output_dir=''):
    if output_dir:
        output_dir = makedir(path=output_dir)
        filename = os.path.join(output_dir, filename)
    return filename

def makedir(path):
    path = os.path.abspath(path)
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)
    return path

## Define output directory
OUTPUT_DIR_HEADLINES = 'output/headlines'
OUTPUT_DIR_AUDIO = 'output/audio'

## Extract data and tabulate as a pandas dataframe
df = tabulate_headlines(text="", filename="test.txt", verbose=1)

## Determine target rows
target_rows_headlines = ~df.headline_text.isna()
target_rows_mp3 = ~df.mp3_url.isna()

## Write headlines to .txt files
print('Total headlines: {}'.format(target_rows_headlines.sum()))
_ = (df
        .loc[target_rows_headlines, ["source_id", "headline_text"]]
        .apply(lambda row: write_headline(text = row['headline_text'],
                                          filename = row['source_id'],
                                          output_dir=OUTPUT_DIR_HEADLINES),
               axis=1))
print('Writing headlines to .txt files: COMPLETE')

## Save audio to .mp3 files
print('Total audio files: {}'.format(target_rows_mp3.sum()))
_ = (df
        .loc[target_rows_mp3, ["source_id", "mp3_url"]]
        .apply(lambda row: download_mp3(url = row['mp3_url'],
                                        filename = row['source_id'],
                                        output_dir=OUTPUT_DIR_AUDIO),
               axis=1))
print('Downloading audio to .mp3 files: COMPLETE')
```

Comment: you would be better to try to make a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle what do you mean?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Yuri, @Chris is suggesting that you use an example that is the smallest one possible that retains the essence of the problem. Including reams of code is a sure-fire way to cause readers to lose interest after a quick scan and move on to the next question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with your regex that makes the headline_data `headline_text_pat = r"\n?\[headline - https://.*/(.*?)\.html\]\n((.*\n)+?)\n"`

If you run this regex against your sample file, you will see capture group one stores the end of the URl, group 2 captures the next two lines, and group three captures the last of those two lines

```
Match 1
Full match  0-99    
[headline - https://www.rfa.org/cantonese/news/us-pompeo-06012020072305.html]
This
some-text-here

Group 1.    47-71   
us-pompeo-06012020072305

Group 2.    78-98   
This
some-text-here

Group 3.    83-98   
some-text-here
```

so the issue is not that your appending to the text file more than once when its the last line, the issue is in your source data.

```py
        for headline in headline_data:
            print("#", headline)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
# ('us-pompeo-06012020072305', 'This\nsome-text-here\n', 'some-text-here\n')
# ('tw-uk-06012020113435', 'Is\nsome-text-here\n', 'some-text-here\n')
# ('wang-06012020103828', 'Test\nsome-text-here\n', 'some-text-here\n')
# ('us-wang-06012020135251', 'TEST\nsome-text-here\n', 'some-text-here\n')
# ('hk-chan-06012020073718', 'TEST\nsome-text-here\n', 'some-text-here\n')
# ('ear-state-06012020035108', 'TEST\nsome-text-here\n', 'some-text-here\n')
```

So you can see that you actually have "some-text-here" twice in your data because of your regex so your append does just what you ask and appends it, you need to look at your regex and change it to stop picking up like this.